p4v how to backout one cl with add , edit ,edit , delete histroy
perforce, how to backout one cl with add , edit ,edit , delete histroy with cmd command line
need backout add cl
https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/3474
To back out changelist 1000 in this scenario, you use the following steps:
p4 sync @999
p4 edit //depot/ola.txt
p4 add //depot/bar.txt
p4 sync @1000
p4 resolve -ay
p4 sync
p4 resolve
p4 delete //depot/foo.txt
p4 submit
p4
for add status command ,it seems not right
when i try to do it with perforce client, at last keep edit file ,not marked with delete status
p4 backout work and get latest policy
